# how to get multiple rows fit into one cell in xmlattributes

Tags: html, xml, oracle

Im using xmlelement to write a piece of html code in oracle.

my current database stores these data

```
+---------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| menu_id | title          | url                   | upper_lvl |
+---------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|       1 | Forms          | null                  |         0 |
|       2 | Basic forms    | forms-basic.html      |         1 |
|       3 | Extended forms | forms-extended.html   |         1 |
|       4 | Validation     | forms-validation.html |         1 |
|       5 | Wizard321      | forms-wizard.html     |         1 |
+---------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

here is the format that i want to get:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
      <a href="forms-basic.html">Basic forms</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="forms-extended.html">Extended forms</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="forms-validation.html">Validation</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="forms-wizard.html">Wizard</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

im trying to use this code below to get the result but i know it will not work cause the inner query returns more than one row. just put it here if anyone can modify from that or other solution is welcomed.

```
select 
  xmlelement("ul",
    xmlattributes('dropdown-menu' as "class"),
    xmlelement("li",
      xmlelement("a",
        xmlattributes(url as "href"),
        (select title from att1 where upper_lvl = 1)
      )
    )
  )

from att1
where menu_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use XMLAgg (XML aggregate function) to achieve this

```
select 
  xmlelement("ul", xmlattributes('dropdown-menu' as "class"),
      XMLAgg(xmlelement("li",
                        xmlelement("a",
                        xmlattributes(url as "href"),title) as "Menu Element"
                        ) 
            )
          ) as Menu
    from att1 where upper_lvl = 1
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you

Comment: beautiful, that's exactly what am i looking for. thanks, it worked well